# Car controlled by steering wheel

Tags: c#, unity3d

I'm a young coder who is looking to improve in my coding practices because I was told by my supervisor to look into a more healthier method to code.

What I would like to ask is how can I improve my coding structures? For example, is using a whole lot of `bool` to check for conditions considered acceptable? // Other than commenting it.

PS : I'm not going to present an updated copy of the code to my supervisor, I just want to improve myself for next time.

PSS : I study coding, but for coding structures, I was only taught the theory. There were no coding assignments.

PSSS : This code here is for a car in Unity that can drive back and front using a Logitech steering wheel GT Force.

I don't really know where else to ask since I'm put to internship and I won't be meeting my lecturers for a long time.

Here is an example of a code I've recently worked on:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// DEBUG : Make sure when alternating between pedals, the momentum is still there

public class VehicleMovements : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody vehicleRigidbody;
    private Transform vehicleTransformer;
    public float momentum;
    private float turning;

    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField]
    float reverseSpeed;
    [SerializeField]
    float steeringWheel;
    [SerializeField]
    float turningSpeed; // 1
    [SerializeField]
    float pedal;
    [SerializeField]
    float momentumMultiplier; // 1.05
    [SerializeField]
    float startOffSpeed; // 0.05

    // Can change to private when done testing
    [SerializeField]
    bool isPedal;
    [SerializeField]
    bool isBrake;
    [SerializeField]
    bool hasBrakeReset;
    [SerializeField]
    bool stillBacking;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        vehicleRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        vehicleTransformer = GetComponent<Transform>();
        reverseSpeed -= (reverseSpeed + reverseSpeed);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        steeringWheel = Input.GetAxis("SteeringWheel");
        pedal = Input.GetAxis("Pedal");

        if (pedal > 0.1)
        {
                hasBrakeReset = true;
                isBrake = false;
                stillBacking = false;
                if (!isPedal)
                {
                    momentum = startOffSpeed;
                    isPedal = true;
                }
                if (momentum <= pedal) momentum *= momentumMultiplier;
                else momentum /= momentumMultiplier;
                moveVehicle(moveSpeed);
        }
        else if (pedal >= 0 && pedal <= 0.1)
        {
            if (momentum > pedal) momentum /= momentumMultiplier;
            else if (momentum < 0.1)
            {
                momentum = 0;
            }
            isPedal = false;
            isBrake = false;
            if (!stillBacking)
                moveVehicle(moveSpeed);
            else
                moveVehicle(-moveSpeed);
        }
        else
        {
                stillBacking = true;
                isPedal = false;
                hasBrakeReset = false;
                if (!isBrake)
                {
                    isBrake = true;
                    momentum = startOffSpeed;
                }
                if (momentum <= -pedal) momentum *= momentumMultiplier;
                else momentum /= momentumMultiplier;
                moveVehicle(reverseSpeed);
        }

        if(pedal >= 0 && hasBrakeReset)
        {
            if (momentum != 0)
            {
                turning += ((steeringWheel * momentum) * turningSpeed);
                vehicleTransformer.Rotate(transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, turning, 0));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            turning += -((steeringWheel * momentum) * turningSpeed);
            vehicleTransformer.Rotate(transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, turning, 0));
        }
    }

    void moveVehicle(float speed)
    {
        var v3 = transform.forward * (momentum * speed);
        v3.y = vehicleRigidbody.velocity.y;
        vehicleRigidbody.velocity = v3;
    }
}
```

Comment: this could be more OOP. why not have a separate Pedal class and use polymorphism to supply the required behaviour: if (pedal > 0.1)  or if (pedal >= 0 && pedal <= 0.1) or if otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer:** you can use `Dictionary<string, float>` instead of declaring many `float`. I didn't use `Array` or `List` because we need naming values instead of using `index`.

next I use enum....why I didn't use `Dictionary<string, bool>`?

because enum & switch is better than using Dictionary for conditions.However, if the conditions were related you should use Dictionary.

```
if(a && b && c) -> use Dictionary<string, bool>
if(a || b || c) -> use enum
```

Well this isn't confusing.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class VehicleMovements : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody vehicleRigidbody;
    private Transform vehicleTransformer;
    public float momentum;
    private float turning;

    public Dictionary<string, float> CarFloats = new Dictionary<string, float>()
    {
    {"steeringWheel",0},
    {"turningSpeed",0},
    {"pedal",0},
    {"momentumMultiplier",1},
    {"moveSpeed",1.5f},
    {"startOffSpeed",0.05f},
    };


    public enum Modes { pedal , brake , hasBrakeReset,stillBacking };
    public Modes modes;


    void Update() 
    {
        if(CarFloats["steeringWheel"] == 0)
        {
            print("hello");
        }

        switch (modes)
        {
            case Modes.pedal: print("pedal");
                break;
            case Modes.brake: print("brake");
                break;
            case Modes.hasBrakeReset: print("hasBrakeReset");
                break;
            case Modes.stillBacking: print("stillBacking");
                break;
            default: print("None");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Another way to prevent confusing is using [CustomEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html).you can grouping your variables by using [Foldout](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Foldout.html).

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class VehicleMovements : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody vehicleRigidbody;
    private Transform vehicleTransformer;
    public float momentum;
    private float turning;

    //HideInInspector This allows you hide public variables in inspector
    //floats
    [HideInInspector]
    public float reverseSpeed,
    moveSpeed,
    steeringWheel,
    turningSpeed = 1,
    pedal,
    momentumMultiplier = 1.5f,
    startOffSpeed = 0.05f;


    [HideInInspector]
    //booleans
    public bool isPedal,
    isBrake,
    hasBrakeReset,
    stillBacking;
}
```

Create Folder as Editor and put this script in it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(VehicleMovements))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects()]
public class TriggerEditor : Editor
{
    public bool CarFloats = true;
    public bool CarBooleans = true;

    override public void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        //if you need DefaultInspector use this (it works like base class in overriding)
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        //2 space
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.Space();
        }
        //use VehicleMovements class variables
        VehicleMovements targetPlayer = (VehicleMovements)target;

        //grouping variables by Foldout
        CarFloats = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(CarFloats, "Car Floats");

        //if click
        if (CarFloats)
        {

            targetPlayer.reverseSpeed = EditorGUILayout.Slider("ReverseSpeed", targetPlayer.reverseSpeed, 0, 100);
            targetPlayer.steeringWheel = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("SteeringWheel", targetPlayer.steeringWheel);
            targetPlayer.turningSpeed = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("TurningSpeed", targetPlayer.turningSpeed);
            targetPlayer.pedal = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Pedal", targetPlayer.pedal);
            targetPlayer.momentumMultiplier = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("MomentumMultiplier", targetPlayer.momentumMultiplier);
            targetPlayer.startOffSpeed = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("StartOffSpeed", targetPlayer.startOffSpeed);

        }

        //2 space
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.Space();
        }

        //grouping variables by Foldout
        CarBooleans = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(CarBooleans, "Car Booleans");

        if (CarBooleans)
        {

            targetPlayer.isPedal = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("IsPedal", targetPlayer.isPedal);
            targetPlayer.isBrake = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("IsBrake", targetPlayer.isBrake);
            targetPlayer.hasBrakeReset = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("HasBrakeReset", targetPlayer.hasBrakeReset);
            targetPlayer.stillBacking = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("StillBacking", targetPlayer.stillBacking);
            targetPlayer.isPedal = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("IsPedal", targetPlayer.isPedal);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

but this is simple example of using `CustomEditor`
I already replied to a question in relation to `CustomEditor` so [this useful link for you](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121767/how-can-i-add-a-new-item-to-my-enum-list-in-the-inspector/121769#121769)
[image]

---

Your obvious problem in your code is that you have longer `FixedUpdate`.I wonder why you didn't use the functions in your code.

this is part of your code that i try to use functions to clearing and improving your code.

```
void Start()
{
    InitializeComponents();
}


void InitializeComponents()
{
    vehicleRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    vehicleTransformer = GetComponent<Transform>();
    reverseSpeed -= (reverseSpeed + reverseSpeed);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Axis();
    CheckPedal();
}


void Axis()
{
    steeringWheel = Input.GetAxis("SteeringWheel");
    pedal = Input.GetAxis("Pedal");
}

void CheckPedal(){
    if (pedal > 0.1)
    {
        BrakeReset();
    }
    else if (Pedal)
    {
        print("blah blah")
    }
}

void BrakeReset()
{
    hasBrakeReset = true;
    isBrake = false;
    stillBacking = false;
    if (!isPedal)
    {
        momentum = startOffSpeed;
        isPedal = true;
    }
    if (momentum <= pedal) momentum *= momentumMultiplier;
    else momentum /= momentumMultiplier;
    moveVehicle(moveSpeed);
}


public bool Pedal() {
    if (pedal >= 0 && pedal <= 0.1)
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

I recommend if you're looking for clean code you should know about:

[Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

[Encapsulation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_encapsulation.htm)

[image]

Comment: Holy, thanks for the very well and easy to understand explanation!

Comment: Just curious why Dictionary<string, int> rather than Dictionary<enum, int>. Would create compile time errors rather than run time in case of typos and saves the next developer scrolling to see what's in the dictionary

Comment: @MikeyMouse Looks good!!! thanks for commenting